# Recreate activity with closed drawer after drawer menu click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to recreate activity after navigation drawer menu is clicked and close this drawer.

I've tried this:

```
private void drawerItemClicked(int position) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer);
    //...
    recreate();
}
```

but doesn't work well. Drawer is starting to close, but screen blacks out for sec and activity is recreated with opened drawer.

Do I have to handle drawer state by myself with `onSaveInstanceState()` or there is other way?

Comment: also try to put  drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer); in OnCreate of the activity

Comment: make drawerLayout and drawer global in scope

Comment: @Softcoder won't it mess up handle rotation with opened drawer?

Comment: see this  http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html   .. i hope it helps

Comment: Try starting it via a new Intent as opposed to recreate(), and then call finish after you start the new intent.

Comment: @zgc7009 I guess that's what I was looking for. It works and black screen blink doesn't show up. Maybe post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that you cleanly recreate your Activity without worrying about the framework handling something in an unexpected way with `recreate()` you can explicitly declare a fresh new instance of the Activity by creating a new Intent. Something like

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, CurrentActivity.class));
finish();
```

Calling `finish()` after you start the new Activity via the Intent, will finish the underlying (paused state) Activity. This will essentially "recreate" your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but maybe my solution can be of use to someone else. I ran into the same issue today.

Apparently the problem is that the framework has not completely closed the navigation drawer when the activity is recreated. Therefore I moved the recreate() call to the onDrawerClosed listener, like this:

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
    //...
    if(...)
        recreate();
}
```

It works perfectly and the drawer stays put when the activity restarts.